# jquery key up firing multiple time

Tags: php, jquery

i have this code:

```
$("#search").keydown(function (e) {
    var str = $(this).val();
    alert(str);
    var url = $("#url").val() + "?ajax=true&q=" + str;
    $("#tableWrap").load(url, function () {});
});
```

`#search` is id of a textbox that filter information shown in a table. when i type in that for first key the function is firing one time . when i type second key in it the function is firing two time ... .any idea?

Edit:all code.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
             //   $("#search").val("جست و جو...");
                $("#search").live('click', function(){
                    $(this).val("");
                });
                  $("#search").keyup(function (e) {

                       var str = $(this).val();
                       alert(str);
                       var url = $("#url").val() + "?ajax=true&q=" + str;

                       $("#tableWrap").load(url, function(){
                           });


                  });


           /*     $("#search").live('keyup', function(){

                    var str = $(this).val();
                    var url = $("#url").val() + "?ajax=true&q=" + str;
                    $("#tableWrap").load(url, function(){
                       // $("#search").focus().val(str);
                    });

                });*/

                $(".pg_class a").live('click',function(){
                    showLoading();
                    $("#load").fadeIn("slow");
                    loadAJAX(this+"&ajax=true");
                    return false;
                });
                $("#tableWrap th").live('click',function(){
                    showLoading();
                    $("#load").fadeIn("slow");
                    loadAJAX($(this).children("a").attr("href") + "&ajax=true");
                    return false;
                });
                $("#tableWrap th a").live('click',function(){
                    showLoading();
                    $("#load").fadeIn("slow");
                    //alert($(this).attr("href"));
                //  alert("salam");
                    loadAJAX($(this).attr("href") + "&ajax=true");
                    return false;
                });
                $(".header select").live('change',function(){
                    showLoading();
                    $("#load").fadeIn("slow");
                    var pageSize = $('.header select option:selected').text();

                    var url = $('.header select').val();

                //    alert(url+pageSize+"&ajax=true");
                    loadAJAX(url+pageSize+"&ajax=true");
                });
            });
        </script>
```

Comment: Is you keydown handler nested inside an other handler?

Comment: Can you post the surrounding code?

Comment: @ Dhaval Marthak problem is not by keyup.

Comment: @roasted no it is not.

Comment: My guess is the when you are doing the jQuery .load() the html you are getting back includes the same script to add the keydown listener thus you have two keydown listeners after the first. You will want in your php to code to not include the javascript event handlers if the request is an ajax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for future.
i solve the problem with this:

```
  jQuery("#search").one("keyup", function (e) {
                      var str = $(this).val();

                       var url = $("#url").val() + "?ajax=true&q=" + str;

                       $("#tableWrap").load(url, function(){
                           });
                  });
```